# Can't draw largest contour

Tags: opencv, drawing, contour

I have the following code to draw the largest contour. But It seems there is something that I am doing wrong. Please advice

```
if(inputImage.data == NULL)
        return HandInfo2();
        Mat outputImage =  Mat::zeros( inputImage.size(), CV_8UC1);
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        vector<Point> largestContour;
        int largestArea = -1;

    findContours( inputImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    /// Approximate contours to polygons
    vector<vector<Point> > polyContours( contours.size() );
    
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), polyContours[i], 3, true );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        int area = fabs(contourArea(polyContours[i],false));
        if(area > largestArea && area > size)
        {
            largestArea = area;
            largestContour = polyContours[i];
        }   
    }

    Scalar color = Scalar( 255 );

    if(largestContour.size()>0)
    drawContours( outputImage, largestContour, 0, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
```

When drawContours() is being called, I get the following error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < 0) in unknown function, file  ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 957

[image: THE ERROR]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello, it seems to me that you can optimise this. Instead of looping through the contours and storing the largest in `largestContour`, you could simply store the index of the largest contour so you do not have to copy contours multiple times. Then, you can simply access the largest contour in `polyContours` by its index... what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for someone who makes the same mistake.

I needed the a `vector<vector<Point>> largestContour;` instead of vector largestContour;

And changed the code from `largestContour = polyContours[i];` to `largestContour.push_back(polyContours[i]);`

That was it. Now I can extract the largest contour.